# Is there a way to drive the developers of Ubuntu to reduce the native mouse-clicks for shutting down from four times to one or two?

Tags: mouse, shutdown, gui, 21.10

To shut down I have to click on the power button top right, then on `shutdown/power off` to expand the menu, then on `shutdown` and then a final window pops on asking me if I am sure.

[image]

Is this necessary? Why is there not ONE button to switch off? Why do Ubuntu developers think it is a good way to having people install add-ons or hack around to beeing able to do this?

Comment: Probably because humans are remarkably inaccurate when pointing with anything but a finger. Heck, based on the sort of things colleagues ask for help with, the myriad of "Are you sure" confirmations one faces throughout the day do little to stop unintentional actions. All this aside, would removing the shutdown confirmation be sufficient?

Comment: If you ask me I would say the extra step 2 that came in to expand the menu is too much. I would rather remove this one instead of the final confirmation to shutdown. Just present the menu as large as it is shown on my picture when clicking top right (of course also cancel the extra line `shutdown/logoff` then).

Comment: You are right @bomben. The shutdown, restart or logout sequence was much more efficient in 18.04.

Comment: @vanadium I rephrased my question.

Comment: The Ubuntu developers have repeatedly stated that they want to carry as close to upstream Gnome as possible, are not interested in maintaining a lot of patches or customizations, and generally refer design suggestions to Gnome. Complaints or rants about Gnome design should be directed to the nearest trash bin. *Constructive participation* in Gnome design is welcomed by the Gnome developers.

Comment: @user535733 I am not familiar with who is doing which part of development but I am thankful for the clarification. However, I think the criticism I posted was quite constructive.

Comment: The phrasing rides the line between constructive vs. complaint in my culture. Gnome developers, like people everywhere, can be a bit touchy and defensive if approached in the wrong way. The term *participation* means exactly that -- the Gnome designers tend to ignore drive-by ideas and listen only to folks who stick around and contribute.

Comment: I appreciate your input. I updated my Ubuntu and recognised the issue. Then I read the linked answer here (to which mine was a duplicate) and all those answers suggest working around the issue, basically saying: What you want to do (click once to shutdown) is not the right way to do it. I think if you develop something you should be able to hear "normal" people that are not involved in the engineering process but who are using the software. However, I would be happy to contribute, especially on this issue. How should I do it? Can I file a feature request somewhere? Might I even code?

Comment: @user535733 I know the question was deleted, but did you read my last questions relating to it? where/how can I contribute?

Comment: Start the process of participation and contribution at gnome.org.